# how to concate multiple rows obtained as result of single query and also append single quote before and after each value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as admin_emp_leave_header which contains a column as START_DATE.

Suppose I use the following query to get those dates as:

```
select START_DATE sd 
from admin_emp_leave_header;
```

I get following result

```
SD
--------
01-01-2017
02-01-2017
03-01-2017
04-01-2017
```

But I want the output as

```
SD
----------------------------------------------------
'01-01-2017','02-01-2017','03-01-2017','04-01-2017'
```

How do I get this using oracle?

Comment: Use `listagg()`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `DATE` to text using the `TO_CHAR` function and then concatenate these strings using the `LISTAGG` function:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(start_date,'''MM-DD-YYYY'''),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY start_date)
FROM admin_emp_leave_header
```

If you also needed to get the current date with the same format in case the previous query didn't return any records, you just need to use `NVL`:

```
SELECT NVL(LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(start_date,'''MM-DD-YYYY'''),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY start_date),TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'''MM-DD-YYYY'''))
FROM admin_emp_leave_header
```

Comment: Also can you please help with a query? If the result is null then I want the output as 'SYSDATE' in place of null